# Graphics2D Error

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, graphics2d

I'm trying to create ASCII art and this error keeps showing up. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Antialiased text mode is not compatible with Global antialiasing enable key
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.setRenderingHint(SunGraphics2D.java:1187)
    at visualgrammar.Visualgrammar.main(Visualgrammar.java:21)

This is my code:

```
package visualgrammar;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Vg {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width = 150;
    int height = 30;

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width,height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics a = image.getGraphics();
    a.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 22));

    Graphics2D a2 = (Graphics2D) a;
    a2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    a2.drawString("VISUAL GRAMMAR", 10, 20);

    for(int y=0; y<height;y++) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x=0; x < width; x++) {
        builder.append(image.getRGB(x, y)== -16777216 ? "" : "VG"); 
}

        System.out.println(builder);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Read the [permitted values for RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_ANTIALIASING).  None of the allowed values contain ‘\_TEXT\_’.

Comment: Indeed. I would add that `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON` goes with `KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING`.

Comment: you're right, thank you!